# Java Agent not running when packaged into jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to implement a java agent to run before an application jar, for PoC i have created 2 Java Projects in Eclipse, one is app.java and agent.java,

app.java

```
package test_app;

public class app {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    System.out.println("MAIN JAVA CLASS!!!!");
    
}

}
```

agent.java

```
package java_agent;

import java.lang.instrument.*;

public class agent {

public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    
    System.out.println("INSIDE AGENT");
    
}

}
```

my manifest file for app.java looks like this,

```
Main-Class: test_app.app
Class-Path: .
```

my manifest file for agent.java looks like this,

```
PreMain-Class: java_agent.agent
```

I have executed for both with these commands,

```
javac app.java
javac agent.java

jar -cvfm app.jar manifest.txt app.class
jar -cvfm agent.jar manifest.txt agent.class
```

then I am copying the .jar file sinto another directory and running,

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar -jar app.jar
```

but the combination, it not working and giving errors like this,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: agent_app.agent
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:431)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
 *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
 FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

Kindly help me to fix this and how to do it. I am doing entirely on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously: you should move your .class file into your specified package(path), and which are test_app and java_agent.

After you have done this, make the jar and run, it should be ok.

Besides, why don't you make the jar using eclipse?

Comment: Thanks Vivia, for the answer, I have used Eclipse to create the test_app jar, but for the agent I am confused which one to use "JAR File" or Running JAR File" options. By moving the .class file to test_app and java_agent, you mean to say I need to put agent.class and app.class in the  test_app and java_agent? Sorry for asking a silly question.

Comment: since you declared the agent class in package java_agent, so you need to put the .class file into the same package.